# Display map with Osm in Side server

Tags: c#, .net, openstreetmap

i want to create a web application that displays a map using OSM, and i want all the treatment to be server-side so is there any possibility to do that and can use it with C# ????

Thank you.

Comment: What's a "side server"?

Comment: actually this is what is asked from me so i make a research and i found that the code should be executed in the server and not in the browser , not like using openlayer which is client side .

Comment: Then please use "server-side", but not "side server".

All solutions will need at least some client-side code to run. Except if you want a static map where no user-interaction is possible (i.e. panning and zooming). While OpenLayers (and Leaflet) do need some client-side code, most of the work is done server-side (rendering and serving of tiles).

Currently your question is not clear enough to get answered.

Comment: ok am sorry for the confusion , and am thinking  of using gmap.net but am not sure if it works on a web site because it's dedicated to windows form

Answer (score 0):

you can use [google map maker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) or find here some examples you can impliment according to your need.